# (python, beautifulsoup) When a 'td' contains certain string, take the whole tr

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have a html code that has multiple **'tr'** which at the same time every **'tr'** has multiple **'td'** inside. Im interested in getting only the entire **'tr'** that contains a **'td'** with a x string and i want the code to filter out all the **'tr'** that doesn't contain a **'td'** inside with that x string.
Is that possible?. I'm new to this and i spent hours looking for a solution but i couldn't.

Here for example i want to get the entire **'tr'** of those that contains a **'td'** with string "**acid blob**"

```
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td><b><a href="http://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/abyssal calamaries">abyssal calamaries</a></b></td>
                                    <td><img loading="lazy" src="images/monsters/abyssal_calamaries.gif" alt="abyssal calamaries"></td>
                                    <td>2020-05-28</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>47246</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    
                                 </tr><tr>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td><b><a href="http://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/acid blobs">acid blobs</a></b></td>
                                    <td><img loading="lazy" src="images/monsters/acid_blobs.gif" alt="acid blobs"></td>
                                    <td>2020-05-28</td>
                                    <td>325</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>93153</td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    
                                 </tr><tr>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td><b><a href="http://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/acolytes of darkness">acolytes of darkness</a></b></td>
                                    <td><img loading="lazy" src="images/monsters/acolytes_of_darkness.gif" alt="acolytes of darkness"></td>
                                    <td>2020-11-11</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>4569</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate the `td` tags and use `.find_parent('tr')` to move backup to the `tr` tag.

(`.parent` also works here)

```
>>> len([td.find_parent('tr') for td in soup.find_all('td', string='acid blobs')])
1
>>> len(soup.find_all('tr'))
3
```

https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#going-up

Comment: i did it using the find_parent function thank you good sir